# Why does filter_var treats all IP addresses as in private/reserved range?

Tags: php

I am writing a function which should determine if the client IP (taken using `_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`) is a valid IP, and if so, is it a private/reserved IP address (such as `127.0.0.1`, `192.168.1.100`, etc.)

For some reason, Every IP that I use, With or without VPN enabled, PHP treats it as both in private and reserved range.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
function ip($an_ip_address) {
    $flags = [
        "validate" => FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,
        "ipv4"     => FILTER_FLAG_IPV4,
        "ipv6"     => FILTER_FLAG_IPV6,
        "reserved" => FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE,
        "private"  => FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE,
    ];
    $info = [
        "ip"       => $an_ip_address,
        "valid"    => false,
        "type"     => "IPv",
        "reserved" => false,
        "private"  => false,
    ];

    $info["valid"] = filter_var($an_ip_address, $flags["validate"], $flags["ipv4"]|$flags["ipv6"]) !== false;
    if (!$info["valid"]) {
        $info["type"] = null;
        return $info;
    }
    // Otherwise
    $info["type"] .= strval(filter_var($an_ip_address, $flags["validate"], $flags["ipv4"]) !== false ? 4 : 6);

    // Now let's check if is in private range
    if (filter_var($an_ip_address, $flags["validate"], $flags["ipv4"]|$flags["private"]) !== false) {
        // An reserved IPv4 address
        $info["private"] = true;
    } else if (filter_var($an_ip_address, $flags["validate"], $flags["ipv6"]|$flags["private"]) !== false) {
        // An reserved IPv4 address
        $info["private"] = true;
    }

    // Or in reserved range
    if (filter_var($an_ip_address, $flags["validate"], $flags["ipv4"]|$flags["reserved"]) !== false) {
        // An reserved IPv4 address
        $info["reserved"] = true;
    } else if (filter_var($an_ip_address, $flags["validate"], $flags["ipv6"]|$flags["reserved"]) !== false) {
        // An reserved IPv4 address
        $info["reserved"] = true;
    }

    return $info;
}

// Let's check it out
foreach (["87.249.132.40","108.36.9.244","122.20.178.25"] as $ip) {
    $ip = ip($ip);
    echo json_encode($ip, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).PHP_EOL;
}
```

And the result is that EVERY ip address is considered as in private & reserved ranges:

```
{
    "ip": "87.249.132.40",
    "valid": true,
    "type": "IPv4",
    "reserved": true,
    "private": true
}

{
    "ip": "108.36.9.244",
    "valid": true,
    "type": "IPv4",
    "reserved": true,
    "private": true
}

{
    "ip": "122.20.178.25",
    "valid": true,
    "type": "IPv4",
    "reserved": true,
    "private": true
}
```

So what is wrong with my code?

**Using PHP 8.1.8 on Win10 Enviroment**

Comment: Your usage of `!== false` is wrong. If `filter_var` returns false it is invalid. https://3v4l.org/EhSV4

Comment: @ChrisHaas But that's the whole point: It is treated as reserved/private while it isn't

Comment: `87.249.132.40` is not private, which is why it gets returned from the function as-is. `192.168.1.1` _is_ private, which is why the function returns false.